# How can we discover the machine name of $conf keys?

Tags: 7

This is part of an interview questions and I am not sure. How can we discover the machine name of $conf keys from standard administrative settings forms by inspecting the DOM? (Assume it is in drupal 7)

Answer (score 2):

By literally looking at the DOM.

For a random example, take the aggregate CSS checkbox on the Performance page:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-preprocess-css">
 <input type="checkbox" id="edit-preprocess-css" name="preprocess_css" value="1" class="form-checkbox">  
 <label class="option" for="edit-preprocess-css">Aggregate and compress CSS files. </label>
</div>
```

You'll find the machine name for the variable in the `name` attribute of the associated `<input>` element. In this case, `preprocess_css`.